# Microsoft azure deploy error 40 %

Tags: eclipse, deployment, azure

I´m deploying a simple application in the cloud. I'm using **Eclipse** for this, but the deploy fail.

#### In the console the error is:

> ```
> 09/16/2012 09:40:46 - Configuring Remote Desktop
> 09/16/2012 09:40:50 - Uploading Deployment Package
> 09/16/2012 09:44:58 - Failed uploading deployment package (.cspkg).
> ```

The deploy is only completed **until 40%**.

#### In the log of Eclipse says:

> !ENTRY WAEclipsePlugin 4 0 2012-09-16 09:42:57.026
>        !MESSAGE Error
>        !STACK 0
>        com.gigaspaces.azure.util.CommandLineException: Timeout
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureRestUtils.execute(WindowsAzureRestUtils.java:301)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureRestUtils.execute(WindowsAzureRestUtils.java:338)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureRestUtils.runStorage(WindowsAzureRestUtils.java:393)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureStorageServices.putBlock(WindowsAzureStorageServices.java:358)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureStorageServices.access$0(WindowsAzureStorageServices.java:348)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureStorageServices$UploadingTask.call(WindowsAzureStorageServices.java:79)
>        at com.gigaspaces.azure.rest.WindowsAzureStorageServices$UploadingTask.call(WindowsAzureStorageServices.java:1)
>        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Could you help me please?

Comment: May I ask the size of your Azure Package?

Comment: The size of the package (WindowsAzurePackage.cspkg) is 133 Mb   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the size if the main issue here because I have seen such issue. To ensure it just try deploying the small less functional version of same app under 30 MB and see if that has any issue. Also even when your package size is still under the limit however 130MB package size is not practical and requires application architecture changes.

You can try keeping the over all size smaller by using:

1. Startup Task to automate the runtime download/install
2. Use other Java Management api to download the application and other component in later phase

Comment: This is a "Hello World" application. It only has a index.jsp with "Hello World". 
Do you know how can I made a smaller app?

Answer (score 0):

the error seems to indicate a problem with your connection (Timeout)

is this consistent? may i ask what version are you using of the eclipse plugin?

Comment: Plugin:                                                               Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java (by MS Open Tech) 1.7.2.201208281306                                                    Windows Azure Access Control Services Filter (by MS Open Tech 0.2.0.201208281306                                                    Package for Windows Azure Libraries for Java (by MS Open Tech) 0.3.0.201208281306
                                                             Eclipse:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Juno Service Release 1 Build id: 20120906-0910