# HelloWorld application does not work when deployed in Windows Azure

Tags: java, deployment, azure, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to deploy a HelloWorld Application using eclips. The program runs successfully in Windows Azure emulator but I cannot publish it in Windows Azure I get the following error message: Failed uploading deployment package. I found a question like mine on this site but no real solution was provided since it suggests to try to make the size smaller :
[Microsoft azure deploy error 40 %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521042/microsoft-azure-deploy-error-40)
Pleased note that it only display a Hello World message I followed the following tutorial: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944(VS.103).aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this problem in slow connection or large deployment packages. I suggest a couple of options:

1) Manually deploy the package using the Windows Azure management portal.

2) Download the latest eclipse plug-in, that now allows you to deploy supporting frameworks (JDK, Tomcat, etc) directly from BLOB storage, so they don't have to become part of the deployment package.

For option #2, you can update the plugin directly in Eclipse. Instructions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx.

The latest release notes are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694270.aspx

I hope this helps.